# Notation of recursive function with multiple arguments

Tags: functions, notation, scientific-notation

I want to formally describe an algorithm $f : E \times P \to P$ which you can use as an argument for itself. Right now, I have the following definition:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P_{e_{n+1}} &= f(e_n, P_{e_n}) \\
&= f(e_n, f(e_{n-1}, f(e_{n-2}, \dots f(e_1, P_{e_1}))))
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The formula should show that you only need one initial $P_{e_1} \in P$ and a set of elements $e_{x} \in E$ to generate $P_{e_{n+1}}$. Is there a name for such a function or a notation that is able to indicate such a characteristic?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* You might want to have a look at *[Ackermann functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function)*.

Comment: @epi163sqrt When I was looking through the Ackermann functions, I also encountered this particular [section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Multivariate_functions) where it was denoted as $f|_{x_i = g}$, do you think this would be applicable in my case? Something along the lines of $f_{e_{x+1}}|_{{x_2} = f_{e_x}}$? Although I would have to rename the $x$ as $x_2$ is the argument, and not related to the $x$ in $e_x$.